# how to use NSDateFormatter to see "Today" string

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

apple use it in the messages app for today messages 
Today 11:45 AM
Yesterday 11:45 AM

i see it in the apple developer site

> To specify a custom fixed format for a date formatter, you use
>   setDateFormat:. The format string uses the format patterns from the
>   Unicode Technical Standard #35. The version of the standard varies
>   with release of the operating system:
>
> Calendar Fields
>
> fields ( alias | (field*, special*)) > field ( alias | (displayName?,
>   relative*, special*)) >
>
> Translations may be supplied for names of calendar fields (elements of
>   a calendar, such as Day, Month, Year, Hour, and so on), and for
>   relative values for those fields (for example, the day with relative
>   value -1 is "Yesterday"). Where there is not a convenient, customary
>   word or phrase in a particular language for a relative value, it
>   should be omitted.

how to use it in Xcode?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

use [`– setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:)

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];

dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;

dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES;

NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

this logs `Today, 11:30 AM` on en_US locales.

Comment: NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter  alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[formatter setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES];

NSDate * date = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);